# why i can make few file object in for loop at java

Tags: java, file, for-loop, file-io

In the following code
I can make f object 4 times without error

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   File f2=new File("D:/"); 
}
```

but java take error for this code for second line
because one time we maked object f

```
File f = new File("D:/");
File f = new File("C:/");
```

why in lopp we can make file object many times with the same name and the same constructor but at second script we can't do it?

Comment: Because of variable scope. In the loop, the `f2` disappears at each iteration. Outside of the loop, you can't have two variables with the same name (well you can, but not in the same scope, so two local variables with the same name won't work as you've noticed).

Comment: Rename the reference variable to f1.In first case the refernce is reasigned.            File f = new File("D:/");
File f1 = new File("C:/");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is equivalent to the following code:

```
{ // block 1 start
    File f2 = new File("D:/");
} // block 1 end

{ // block 2 start
    File f2 = new File("D:/");
} // block 2 end

{ // block 3 start
    File f2 = new File("D:/");
} // block 3 end
```

Each `f2` variable is limited to it's block and is only existent inside of it.  However if you try to declare one variable two times in one block it will fail.

Comment: Just den't declare the variable for a second time. just set it: `f2 = new File("D:/");`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be overwriting the file from the  earlier iteration. That is why your second option works.